# Display contents of text file in man page without formatting

Tags: c, linux, string, indentation, manpage

I'm working on an Open Source contribution. I need to use its `print_usage()` function which contains `printf()` statements for help message (`myprogram --help`) to generate manpage using `myprogram --man` automatically. I've setup command line args to use `freopen()` to print the help message directly to file `myprogram.1`. But when executed with `man -l myprogram.1` it changes the line length which indeed changes the output's expected indentation.

Expected text as in help message:

```
To see This Help Message: -h or --help

File name related options:
            inputfile: file(s) to process
    -o outputfilename: Use -o parameters to define output filename if you don't
                       like the default ones (same as infile plus _1 or _2 when
                       needed and file extension, e.g. .srt).
         -cf filename: Write 'clean' data to a file. Cleans means the ES
                       without TS or PES headers.
              -stdout: Write output to stdout (console) instead of file. If
                       stdout is used, then -o, -o1 and -o2 can't be used. Also
                       -stdout will redirect all messages to stderr (error).
```

Output when `man -l myprogram.1` is executed:

```
To see This Help Message: ‐h or ‐‐help

File name related options:
            inputfile: file(s) to process
    ‐o  outputfilename:  Use ‐o parameters to define output file‐
name if you don’t
                       like the default ones (same as infile plus
_1 or _2 when
                       needed and file extension, e.g. .srt).
         ‐cf filename: Write ’clean’ data to a file. Cleans means
the ES
                       without TS or PES headers.
              ‐stdout: Write output to stdout  (console)  instead
of file. If
                       stdout is used, then ‐o, ‐o1 and ‐o2 can’t
be used. Also
                       ‐stdout  will  redirect  all  messages  to
stderr (error).
```

How can I correct this? I can add sections like NAME, SYNOPSIS, etc. through C code later on but currently I just need to get the formatting right. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
To make it clear. `myprogram.1` obtained doesn't contain any type of `groff` formatting (no macros are used). It's just plain text document having the help message as plain text with indentation.

Comment: Looks like your `man` output is wrapped at 66 columns width. Have you tried playing around with `MANWIDTH`?

Comment: @iVoid Yes, I tried it. It doesn't work either. After setting `MANWIDTH` and even exporting it to `~/.bashrc`, width of all the pages opened using `man` is changed except for this one.